# Java: From a computational perspective, what happens if you set an array as a reference to another array?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, reference

```
int [] arr1 = new int[]{4,6,3,2,7,8};
int [] arr2 = new int[]{6,7,5,3,2,9};
arr2 = arr1;
System.out.println(arr2[3]);  // 2   ( =arr1[3] )
```

The output of this code is 2.

- So what's exactly happening here?
- Is it that arr1 and arr2 are in different memory locations but arr2 is pointing at the values of arr1?
- What happened to the original values of arr2?
- Are they still accessible or were they removed by garbage collection?
- if they are accessible, does the programmer have to free the memory of the 2nd array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what's exactly happening here?

The following will give you a good picture:

**int [] arr1 = new int[]{4,6,3,2,7,8};**  (Create new array, let arr1 point to it)

```
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+
arr1 ---> | 4 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 8 |
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**int [] arr2 = new int[]{6,7,5,3,2,9};** (Create new array, let arr2 point to it)

```
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+
arr2 ---> | 6 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 9 |
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**arr2 = arr1;**  (Let aar2 point to where aar1 is pointing at)

```
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+
arr1 ---> | 4 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 8 |
aar2 ---> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**System.out.println(arr2[3]);** (aar1 & aar2 points to the same array)

```
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+
arr1 ---> | 4 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 8 |
aar2 ---> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
                        ^
                      print
```

> What happened to the original values of arr2?

When the original array pointed by aar2 was unreferenced, it makes it eligible to be collected garbage collection. The garbage collector itself will determine when to collect it.

> Are they still accessible or were they removed by garbage collection?

Garbage collection is automatically done by JVM, and you can't access it after unreferencing it.

Answer (score 4):

`arr1` and `arr2` are both *references*.

Initially they refer to different arrays.

When you write `arr2 = arr1;`, nothing is referring to the second array in your program and so it is indeed eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: You used the word "eligible". Are you implying that the values of the 2nd array aren't garbage collected automatically? If so, is the programmer supposed the to free the memory manually?

Comment: I'm being careful - in saying "eligible" I'm saying that you should regard them as being scheduled for garbage collection and eventually collected. The programmer doesn't need to intervene in any way.

Comment: I see. So the original values of arr2 are no longer accessible?

Comment: And what about in terms of memory? Are arr1 and arr2 both referring to the same memory locations?

Comment: @TheSaviour yes, both are referring to the same memory locations

Comment: *"You used the word "eligible". "* ... Garbage Collection by the JVM has no testable semantics.  It is not possible to say precisely when, or even if, an object that is no longer referenced will be garbage collected.  For the same reason, it is not possible to say when or if finalizer methods on Java objects are executed.  In general, Java programs should never make any assumptions about garbage collections, nor should they be written in such a way that their correctness depends on particular semantics of garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

Those *variables* hold references. So:

```
arr2 = arr1;
```

means two things:

- the reference pointing to the `arr2` array ... gets thrown away
- the variable `arr2` now holds the same reference that `arr1` contains

In other words: after this line, only one array is "left". So arr2[3] refers to the very same array slot as arr1[3] does.

That "lost" array still exists. But the garbage collector will recognize that it is no longer "reachable". This means: in case the GC decides to collect garbage, that lost array will be collected. But please note: the fact that an object is eligible for garbage collection does *not* imply that it gets collected any time soon. It is up to the GC to decide if/when *collection* should happen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, array references behave exactly as any other object references here. So the answers will be the same for any object types.

> Is it that arr1 and arr2 are in different memory locations but arr2 is
>   pointing at the values of arr1?

The references are in separate locations, but contain the same address which is what used to be only arr1 address at first.

> What happened to the original values of arr2?

The original arr2 array is left unreferenced and is now a candidate for garbage collection. You never know when it's really collected and you don't have direct control of this process.

> Are they still accessible or were they removed by garbage collection?

They are not accessible any more, but it's not guaranteed they are removed immediately. GC has its own algorithms of scheduling such removals.

> if they are accessible, does the programmer have to free the memory of
>   the 2nd array?

No, the programmer doesn't have to free anything manually. In rare cases, for example when you know you will need much memory soon, you can call System.gc() to "ask" the GC to collect the garbage, but there is no guaranteed time limit for it to obey.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `arr1=arr2`, you are assigning reference pointer of `arr2` to `arr1`. The pointer `arr2` is garbage collected. Hence, you don't have control over that variable. Once the object is eligible for garbage collection, it may not be destroyed immediately.

JVM runs Garbage Collector program, then the only object will be destroyed. But you can also request JVM to run the garbage collector. You can do that in 2 ways:

- System.gc()
- Runtime.getRuntime().gc()

You can read more about it [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-java/).